# Multiple countifs with excluded criterior

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to count 2 columns with multiple criteria and excluding other criteria.

For example: I would like to count all cells in column B excluding Hodges Sandringham and Hodges Mentone if column H is blank.

I have the following idea but it is incorrect: =COUNTIFS(Data!B:B,"<>Hodges Mentone"&"<>Hodges Sandringham",Data!H:H,"")[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0p6A.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- `&` and  does not serve to combine different criteria, maybe replace it with:

  `,Data!B:B,`
- `Data!H:H,""` selects blank cells which is unlikely to be useful here. To select non-blank please try:

  `Data!H:H,"<>"`

Hence:

```
 =COUNTIFS(Data!B:B,"<>Hodges Mentone",Data!B:B,"<>Hodges Sandringham",Data!H:H,"<>")
```